# Does EPS have a DPI?

Tags: eps

Some of what I've read about EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) sounds like it assumes 72 dpi. But other parts say because it's vectors that there is no dpi and I can use any units when creating the file as the eps file is then positioned and sized when imported/used.

So which is it?